# Send id along with android c2dm message?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I implemented c2dm in my application.Also am getting c2dm message from the third party server.Is it possible to send an extra "id" value  along with this message(This id should be my application id which am using in app, not any third party id).Is it possible ? can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#push) of c2dm - any key-value can by send by your server to device. Only limit is size of message.